# Why does django not use my SHORT_DATE_FORMAT with date template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have troubles understanding why django doesn't use my SHORT_DATE_FORMAT in templates when I specify it for the date template tag.
My settings are:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Australia/Melbourne'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-AU'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

In my template:

```
{{ asset.upload_date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}
```

I would expect '21/01/2014' but I get '01/21/2014'.

Comment: Shouldn't  USE_L10N be set to False, according to documentation?

Comment: hm that helps, but I'm still confused. Docs say 'If USE_L10N is set to True, Django will display numbers and dates using the format of the current locale.'. My locale is Australian. So it should be d/m/Y not m/d/Y. I found this: from django.utils import formats 
formats.get_format("SHORT_DATE_FORMAT", lang=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE) and it's 'm/d/Y'... wrong IMO :/

Answer (score 1):

It's actually due to `USE_L10N=True` + Django still not having a locale conf for Australia (`en-au/en_AU`) which specifies `d/m/Y`. Bit of an surprise. But it will be there with the release of 1.7

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21237

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/Bgx3u1xtaMc

Comment: Did you find a workaround for 1.6? I still can't get SelectDateWidget to display d/m/Y...

Comment: From looking at the code it uses DATE_INPUT_FORMATS[0], so if you overwrite the setting to make the first entry d/m/Y it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this for 1.6 is create a locale folder in your app folder and to set

[FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'myapp.locale'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#format-module-path)

then copy the en_AU folder from

**https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/locale**

and then add a **init**.py file to the locale folder with

```
LANG_INFO = {
    'en-au': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'en-au',
        'name': 'Australian English',
        'name_local': 'Australian English',
    },
}
```